# MySQL join with 3 tables trick

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I can't obtain the result I want, let me explain:

I have two tables :

- **CATEGORIES**
- **PROJECTS**

and between them another table which makes the link:

- **ASSIGNED_CAT** with 2 columns: `PROJECT_ID` and `CATEGORY_ID`

In `ASSIGNED_CAT` I get the IDs of `CATEGORIES` and `PROJECTS` linked together.

---

Now I need to get the CATEGORIES which contains PROJECTS and if not don't show them.

*Example:*
If CATEGORY 1 have projects display the CATEGORY NAME and if not don't show.

Any idea to trick this? I've tried many SQL JOIN without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing the [`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) clause.

The following query selects all categories, for which at least one row exists in the intersection table.

```
SELECT category_name
FROM categories c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM assigned_cat ac
    WHERE ac.category_id = c.category_id
)
```

Comment: @FahimParkar: It will select one column with the constant value `1`. When using the `EXISTS` clause only the number of rows is relevant, so you could also `SELECT *` or `SELECT ac.category_id`.

Comment: Actually it doesn't really select anything, it won't even evaluate what you are trying to select. You can try this by inducing an "error" by doing where exists ( select 1/0 from .... where ... )