# Can't add another table row condition to my SQL query

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have this query :

```
SELECT category_name, category_id, category_slug
FROM categories
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM assigned_categories
    WHERE assigned_categories.assigned_category_id = categories.category_id
)
```

And I would like to get the value of the `'visible'` field of another `TABLE` called `'posts'` so It will look like this :

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE EXISTS ... AND WHERE 'visible' = 1 of 'ft_projetcs' TABLE
```

I've try many things but I think I'm doing something wrong. Any help?

Comment: I believe this question is continuation to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247298/mysql-join-with-3-tables-trick)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if I understand your problem right, but it sounds like you want to do an inner join?
Try something like this:

```
SELECT category_name, category_id, category_slug
FROM categories
inner join ft_projects on ft_projects.category_id = categories.id
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM assigned_categories
    WHERE assigned_categories.assigned_category_id = categories.category_id
)
and ft_projects.visible = 1
```

Of course you have to adjust your join-condition, the "on ft_projects.category_id = categories.id" is just an example.

Also important: I think what you want to achieve with your exists condition, is also better solved via an inner join (at least I assume so, based on your columns names).

Answer (score 0):

Ok figure it out, this did the trick :

```
SELECT category_name, category_id, category_slug
FROM categories

    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1, visible
        FROM assigned_categories

        JOIN posts ON assigned_categories.assigned_post_id = post_id

        WHERE assigned_categories.assigned_category_id = ft_categories.category_id AND visible = 1
    )
```